# presenting Google Interstials in ios7 using storyboard gives error

Tags: ios, interstitial

I am trying to display Google Interstitial using following code in my iOS 7 app

```
    if(interstitial_.isReady)
    {
        [interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }
```

I get the following error

Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

My app uses storyboard. By using XIB, I could successfully display interstitial. In storyboard how do I define a segue for showing the interstitial ad?

Thanks!

Comment: More info: I created a new app that uses storyboard and used the sample code given in admob documents for creating a splash interstitial. It crashes with the above mentioned error code. Admob sample application does not use storyboard. With an older XIB interface the interstitial works fine.

Comment: I found the solution   http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/11/create-your-own-version-of.html